# While sending mail getting following error

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```
<?php
require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port     = 587;  
$mail->Username = "akilesh1111@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "*********";
$mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddAddress("akilesh1111@gmail.com"); 
$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST["content"]);

if(is_array($_FILES)) {
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']); 
}

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "<p class='error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p class='success'>Contact Mail Sent.</p>";
}   
?>
```

This code is working fine in localhost
When uploading to server then it shows below error
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Problem in Sending Mail.

Comment: make sure the SMTP port is enable to your server

Comment: Go to the following and look for "Allow less secure apps:  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting that is most likely your problem

Comment: You're running an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).